# extension not found : intl and no php.ini

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I am trying to install Magento in it's own sub folder (shop) and get the message:

> Required PHP extension not found : intl

I don't have any php.ini files on my server, except the one I have put in my Wordpress folder.

I read, that what I should do is create a php.ini and put in extension=php_intl.dll but where do I put it?

The Magento installation want to create a folder so I can't premake a folder for it.

Comment: Which magento version ?

Comment: Version 2.1.7  (15chars)

Comment: Which OS you are using ?

Comment: It is hosted on linux and php 5.6.30

Comment: Okay. Is it Ubuntu linux ?

Comment: Ubuntu isn't mentioned in the server info

Comment: Run "uname -a" command and paste output in comment here.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, that is why I wanted a one click service.

Comment: Okay. So do you have cpanel access ?

Comment: Yes and I do know how to use that, sort of

Comment: Okay. May be you can find it in PHP settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, follow below process:

- Create a new file (say: info.php) in the directory where you have put your Magento's setup (for example: /var/www/html folder). Put below code in this file:

**`<?php phpinfo()?>`**

- Go to browser and open http://localhost/info.php. After doing so, you will be able to see a screen like below:

[image]

- Now you need to note PHP version (which is shown like PHP Version x.x.x). Let us say it is 5.6.x. Now run below command:

> apt-get install php5-intl

and then restart your server using:

> service apache2 restart

Now check by reloading Magento installation page.

If still problem exists, please feel free to ask by commenting.

**Note:** You must run these commands as user who has root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5 on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```